# Saving custom field term values from product attribute in WooCommerce admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

For WooCommerce, I created a custom field on attribute term, but I don't know why it is not saving after the term update. User has the necessary permissions.

```php
if (is_admin() && isset($_GET['taxonomy'], $_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'product') {
    $taxonomy_name = sanitize_text_field($_GET['taxonomy']);

    add_action($taxonomy_name . '_edit_form_fields', 'custom_edit_term_fields', 10, 2);

    function custom_edit_term_fields($term, $taxonomy)
    {
        $value = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'custom-term-input', true);

        echo '<tr class="form-field">
    <th>
        <label for="custom-term-input">Custom input</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <input name="custom-term-input" id="custom-term-input" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($value) . '" />
        <p class="description">Description text</p>
    </td>
    </tr>';
    }

    add_action('created_' .  $taxonomy_name, 'custom_save_term_fields');
    add_action('edited_' .  $taxonomy_name, 'custom_save_term_fields');

    function custom_save_term_fields($term_id)
    {
        update_term_meta(
            $term_id,
            'custom-term-input',
            sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom-term-input'])
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always add your hooked functions outside another function or an if statement in your case, as here your functions are triggered by action hooks. Also, what is missing is another hooked function in the admin that will trigger everything and where you are going to add your if statement and the related add_action() triggering your functions.

Try the following untested (maybe the hook admin_init is not the right hook to be used):

```php
 // The main hooked function container
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_edit_and_save_term_fields' );
 function custom_edit_and_save_term_fields() {
    if (isset($_GET['taxonomy']) && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] === 'product') {
        $taxonomy_name = sanitize_text_field($_GET['taxonomy']);
        
        add_action("{$taxonomy_name}_edit_form_fields", "custom_edit_term_fields", 10, 2);
        add_action("created_{$taxonomy_name}", "custom_save_term_fields");
        add_action("edited_{$taxonomy_name}", "custom_save_term_fields");
    }
 }

function custom_edit_term_fields($term, $taxonomy) {
    $value = get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'custom-term-input', true);

    echo '<tr class="form-field">
        <th>
            <label for="custom-term-input">Custom input</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input name="custom-term-input" id="custom-term-input" type="text" value="' . esc_attr($value) . '" />
            <p class="description">Description text</p>
        </td>
        </tr>';
}

function custom_save_term_fields($term_id) {
    update_term_meta($term_id, 'custom-term-input', sanitize_text_field($_POST['custom-term-input']));
}
```

It could work.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer...but it is not working:/ there is no error and custom-term-input meta key is not existing in the termmeta table. I deactivated all plugins (except woocommerce) and changed the theme to storefront, I also tried to rename the meta key but unsuccessfully. If I dump $taxonomy_name there is the same slug as in the attribute term url ... I must say this is multisite and for now every field I added successfully. For example I added custom select on each attribute and now I must also add a field to term ..

Comment: others default fields included in term is saving ok ...